# Best way to include a contact form in Lektor?

Tags: contact-form, static-site, lektor

I am using the CMS Lektor. I need to include a contact form.

What is the best method to include it?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best method, but using 3rd party services is easy and fast.

Examples:

- [Mailchimp](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/host-your-own-signup-forms)
- [Formspree](https://formspree.io/)
- [Google](https://github.com/dwyl/html-form-send-email-via-google-script-without-server)

Answer (score 0):

I have used Formspree and it works very well. Below is code for the Lektor **content.lr** file I used for my contact form:

```
_model: page
---
title: Contact
---
body:
<form method="POST" action="https://formspree.io/whatever.email.you.want.to.use@gmail.com">
<div class="field">
    <label class="label">Name</label>
    <div class="control">
        <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email">
    </div>
</div>    
            
            
<div class="field">
    <label class="label">Message</label>
    <div class="control">                
        <textarea class="textarea" name="message" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="field">
    <div class="control">
        <button class="button is-link" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My live contact form is [here](https://www.jurgengeitner.com/contact/)

**Formspree** have some nice samples too: https://formspree.io/library